# jquery easyui datagrid row link

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I'm trying to write a custom link on a datagrid. The user has the usual functions 'edit', 'add' & 'delete' but I'm also adding 'view'. All my code works apart from the view function but I cannot work out how to open the selected row in a custom url. What I want to achieve is the user selects a row and then clicks the view button which then transfers the id to the report url.

He's my code that works;-

```
    function editOrder(){
        var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
        if (row){
            $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit Order');
            $('#fm').form('load',row);
            url = '/include/functions/edit/edit_order.php?id='+row.id;
```

and here is the code I've tried out but I cant get to work;-

```
    function viewOrder(){
        var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
        if (row){

        $('#fm').form('load',row);
        url = '/include/functions/reports/purchase_order.php?id='+row.id;
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit Order'); is missing the viewOrder code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function viewOrder(){
        var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
        if (row){   
        url = "/include/functions/reports/purchase_order.php?id=" +row.id;
            window.open(url);           
        }
```